# Display ActionBar Search Results In A Spinner

Tags: android, android-actionbar, geocoding

I am trying to add a geocode search function to my application which will work the same way the one in Google Maps does:
[image: An example search in Google Maps For Android]

I have implemented search in the actionbar with an ActionView:
I added an item to the Actionbar:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="97"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="Search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```

And defined how it should be managed in onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    SearchView avSearch = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_Search).getActionView();

    avSearch.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    avSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        int changes = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

            if (changes >= 4 || s.endsWith(" ")) {
                submitLocationQuery(s);
                changes = 0;
            } else
                ++changes;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            submitLocationQuery(query);
            return true;
        }

    });

    return true;
}
```

Searches are fed the Geocoder by a background thread:

```
private void submitLocationQuery(final String query) {
    Thread thrd = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {

                foundAddresses = mGeoCoder.getFromLocationName(query, 5);
                gcCallbackHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Failed to connect to geocoder service", e);
            }
        }
    };
    thrd.start();
}
```

And are recieved and handled by a Handler:

```
private Handler gcCallbackHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (foundAddresses != null && !foundAddresses.isEmpty()) {
            GeoPoint foundGeo = new GeoPoint((int) (foundAddresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (foundAddresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
            mapView.getController().animateTo(foundGeo);
        }
    }
};
```

All of this works and my map zooms to locations when they are searched for, but how can I display my search results under the search like Google Maps does?

Thanks in advance for any response,
ANkh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see in the widget like Spinner are only SUGGESTIONS.

You can obtain this effect following this guide:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-suggestions-to-search/

Or on android developer guide: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html